# Image loading optimization in react native

Tags: react-native

My API responds with image dimensions of 1280X720 and I am using only 110X110 size in my app. Which is increasing the load time and memory consumption too, I believe. How to deal with these cases. How to make my code optimized?

Answer (score 0):

You can compress and resize your image with this [plugin](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer).

```
npm install --save react-native-image-resizer
react-native link react-native-image-resizer
```

Code Sample:

```
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';

ImageResizer.createResizedImage(imageUri, newWidth, newHeight, compressFormat, quality, rotation, outputPath).then((response) => {
  // response.uri is the URI of the new image that can now be displayed, uploaded...
  // response.path is the path of the new image
  // response.name is the name of the new image with the extension
  // response.size is the size of the new image
}).catch((err) => {
  // Oops, something went wrong. Check that the filename is correct and
  // inspect err to get more details.
});
```